# Why would we correlate dark energy to the rate of universal expansion: $dS(x,y,z)/S(x,y,z)$ and not to the flow rate of cosmic time $dt/t$?

Tags: cosmology, time, space-expansion, dark-energy

1. Cosmic time, which is the same from one place to another (at a given instant), is it also the same from one moment to the next?
   To compare the cosmic time at two different instants,
   we would need either:

- Another reference time (outside our Universe) ;
- Or a time unaffected by its expansion.

2. Time in a new sample of 190 high-redshift quasars observed over 20 years by the Sloan Digital Sky Survey (SDSS), Pan-STARRS, and the Dark Energy Survey appears to run five times slower than it does for us in our frame of reference on Earth.

Comment: I feel like there are too many misconceptions here for an answer to have broader value beyond addressing them. (1) There are no "reference times" outside the universe. And every observer's time is (from their own perspective) unaffected by expansion. I suggest trying to understand what time dilation is before thinking about how it relates to dark energy or expansion. (2) Headlines about that study have been very misleading: it isn't saying anything about time in the early universe. It's just a confirmation that if light is redshifted, the events it depicts are slowed by the same factor.